# I'm trying to get sIBL to work, but it won't install the .py addon for it

Tags: add-on

So I installed sIBL and downloaded most of the free HDR images they offer. I loaded up the library files etc, and now I'm ready to use it with some Blender scenes. Well when I click send to software messages pop up saying things along the lines of: "socket connection error" and "loader script raised exception". So yes I'm having trouble and was wondering if anyone here has a solution or could help me.

I'm using Blender 2.76. Windows 64bit. I tried running both as Admin already, and already tried placing the addon directly in the addon's folder for Blender.

Image of the issue:
[image: Firewall on]

This is the error when I turn my firewall off completely:
[image: Firewall off]

Comment: The full error message and [links to the addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/sIBL_GUI) could be helpful. The socket connection error sounds like a network issue, do you have a firewall blocking the port set for the addon to talk to the gui? Try entering your ip address instead of localhost in the settings.

Comment: I added some images with errors putting in my ip didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: The [getaddrinfo failed error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7334199/2684771) indicates a name resolution problem. The connection refused would indicate that the blender addon is not listening, at least not on the port that sibl has configured, it may be that blender cannot attach to the socket number because something else is using it.

Comment: Well I can't get Blender 2.76 to install the addon to start with so I guess I'm just stuck on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Scene Properties there is a section titled `sIBL Gui` in it there are a few buttons,
 1. `Launch sIBL GUI`
 2. `Start Server`
 3. `Stop Server`

Press `Start Server` and you should be able to use the `send to software` button in sIBL_GUI.